# typo3 dce curly brackets rendered twice

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I have a Typo3 v11 installation with DCE 2.9.3. My fluid template seems to be rendered twice, i can write

```
{field:header}
```

and it get's rendered and output the header, i don't need <f:format.raw> or something around! So when i want to insert a json object like

```
{field:header}
<script>
obj = {"json":"awesome"};
</script>
```

the output will be:

```
(Copy 3)
<script>
obj = ;
</script>
```

what's wrong with my installation? When i insert the json object with a <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.obj"></f:cObject> the output will be the same!
where can i find the error? The dce setting "direct output" is active.
I insert a form via f:cobject but the form wont work because the trustedProperties gets replaced:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tx_form_formframework[__trustedProperties]" value=",&quot;linkedcheckbox-1&quot;:1,&quot;__currentPage&quot;:1}}da06e0ab5b4f9e50a25f3d8347c79e9fffaa0505">
```

i search my typoscripts and i dont use replace. I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `asset.script` viewhelper, then I think it will work.

```
{field:header}
<f:asset.script identifier="identifier123"> obj = ; </f:asset.script>
```

For more information, please check this link https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/main/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Asset/Script.html

Answer (score 0):

the root cause it that `{"json":"awesome"}` is parsed as a literal fluid array. which is not rendered at all. but you might use litteral array in arguments for viewhelpers. I would avoid using inline scripts. as this usually leads to trouble because it confuses the renderer

our website usually follow the progressiv enhancment https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement

and we use `data-` attributes to attache "values" to certain elements and external javascript to render the enhanced version out from the data values.

for "highly Dynamic" values. like every customer has its own value we use javascript to fetch the values in an "out of bound" rendering via API so we do not bloat the typo3 cache with million of variations of the same page.

Comment: The problem is not the javascript object itself, i attach in typoscript a form (tx_form)

page.10.variables.CONTENT.20.20 < lib.form

but the output of the trustedpattern is:
<input type="hidden" name="tx_form_formframework[__trustedProperties]" value=",&quot;linkedcheckbox-1&quot;:1,&quot;__currentPage&quot;:1}}da06e0ab5b4f9e50a25f3d8347c79e9fffaa0505">

the form dont work this this replaced content, why?! on a other Typo3 instance they work fine.